# iPad Safari ignores div onclick above html5 video

Tags: ipad, html, video, safari

I've a problem making div element clickable. I've a HTML5 video on screeen, after video end event I create some div element positioned above video with z-index property.
On taping this divs nothing happens, but if this divs are positioned not above video, everything works just fine.
Does anybody have workaround for this thing?

Comment: Does the problem exist on desktop browsers too? Adding z-index is not as straightforward as it seems: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index

Comment: No, desktop browser working fine (IE9, FF9, Chrome 16, Opera 11, Safari 5).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I've just hit it.

Comment: There is no possible solution, which you can implement just by rendering html. It's inside the iOS. Follow my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to work with html elements positioned above HTML5 video on iPad safari, since video is rendered with hardware and displayed above browser. The only workaround I've found is to hide the video when something is displayed above, to make it clickable.

Answer (score 2):

If you disable controls on the video element then it won't steal your click events. You'll then have to create custom controls in order to make it play though!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that will work on both the iPad and iPhone. I tried removing the controls and then add them again, but this worked only on iPad not on iPhone. After remove the opacity and then add it again it worked on iPhone also.

```
$("#overlay_open").click(function(){
  $("video").prop("controls", false);
  $("video").css("opacity", 0);
});

$("#overlay_close").click(function(){
  $("video").prop("controls", true);
  $("video").css("opacity", 1);
});
```