# HTML5 video css background color on iPad

Tags: css, html, ipad, video

Is it currently possible to set the background color of HTML5 video elements effectively? [About HTML5 Audio and Video](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html) points to the fact that you can style video tags with standard CSS, but in my experience this isn't fully working:

- On Chrome 23 (Snow Leopard) adding a poster image attribute to the video tag removes the background color, without a poster image it works as you might expect
- On Safari 5.1.7 everything works correctly
- Perhaps unsurprisingly Mobile Safari on an iPad running iOS 5 is a law until itself. The background color will always be black, no matter what I do. Occasionally I might get a flash of the set css background color before the poster / video load. But even with an empty video tag, the background color won't display.

Anyone had any success setting a background color on iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635899/ipad-safari-ignores-div-onlick-above-html5-video) according HTML 5 on mobile safari.

Seems that it's impossible to control it, as video rendering is delegated to hardware through the browser, and is displayed "above", so controlling css properties of it would not affect anything.

My research was some ago, but don't think that since then anything changed.

Comment: That seems about right, although looking at the answer you mention - you can actually listen for touch events on items sitting above an html5 video element on an ipad, providing you turn off the controls