# What devices / browsers support the background-color attribute on the <video> element?

Tags: css, html, video, cross-browser, background-color

It seems that a range of browsers (some device specific) don't support the `background-color` property. I've created an isolated test here:

http://jsfiddle.net/laustdeleuran/u7WBq/

So far, it seems that IE9 and IE10 doesn't adhere to this property, while Chrome, FF, Opera and Safari (all on PC) do. I'm updating the fiddle as I test.

In some test cases, I do see a quick flash of the red background color on IE10, before the video renders. But the video then renders with black over the red background color, which I'm guessing is probably due to the whole area being hardware accelerated.

[This post on a Metro HTML5 app](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/ad9db181-ddc2-487a-987b-d3f50d92d1e0/) might be related as well as this post on [background-color on videos on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527760/html5-video-css-background-color-on-ipad).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrapping your `<video>` element in a `<div>`. Do your styling on the outer div wrapper and set the *width* and *height* of the video element to *`inherit`*.

Comment: But, Ecropolis, I'm talking about the background-color, not the dimensions of the video. How should the wrapping div fix that?